# Can IFNULL() return a string where the column value is int, using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ifnull

My query

```
select cname, count(screening_occapancy.idclient) as 'Count'
from client, screening_occapancy 
where client.client_no = screening_occapancy.idclient 
group by cname
```

returns the following:

```
Name        Count
Name1        2
Name2        3
Name3        6
```

etc, now I want it the value in 'Count' to be "not found" if the value is null or 0, is that possible? I need something like that in my results:

```
    Name        Count
    Name1         2
    Name2         3
    Name3    "Not found"
```

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is yes: `ifnull(column, "Not Found")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Select cname , 
case when Count is null or count =0 then 'Not found' 
else Count end as count
 from
    (select cname,
 count(screening_occapancy.idclient) as 'Count' 
    from client left join screening_occapancy 
    on
    client.client_no = screening_occapancy.idclient group by cname) t
```

Write a wrapper query above your query to check count column

Comment: Working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join` to get `0` for all not found matches

```
select c.cname, 
       count(so.idclient) as 'Count'
from client c
left join screening_occapancy so on c.client_no = so.idclient 
group by c.cname
```

And BTW don't use the legacy implicit join syntax anymore. Use explicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cname, IF(count(screening_occapancy.idclient)!=0,count(screening_occapancy.idclient),'NOT FOUND') as 'Count'
from client, screening_occapancy 
where client.client_no = screening_occapancy.idclient 
group by cname
```

or if count returns null?

```
select cname, IFNULL(count(screening_occapancy.idclient),'NOT FOUND') as 'Count'
from client, screening_occapancy 
where client.client_no = screening_occapancy.idclient 
group by cname
```